# Unable to install ansible due to python dependency on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ansible, devops

I am trying to install ansible on my Ubuntu 18.04 which throws python depends error. I understand the version installed by default on the machine is 3.x +. The depends requests version of python to be 2.x i. e. 2.7 as per the below log results, Kindly suggest me a better option to install ansible or to downgrade the python version.

```
pawan@ubuntu:~/Devops$ sudo apt install -f ansible
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ansible : Depends: python-jinja2 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python-yaml but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python-paramiko but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python-httplib2 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python-six but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python-crypto (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python-setuptools but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python-cryptography but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
           Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Sorry guys I have pasted the command output twice. Kindly consider the same. Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and simply resolved it with `pip` installation.

```
pip install --user ansible
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead using the PPA for ansible they keep it up-to-date and it should be able to work with the versions of Python in ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y install ansible
```

The above commands will quickly install ansible for you. You can also see Ansible's  official documentation for installing on ubuntu here which mirrors my advice:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#latest-releases-via-apt-ubuntu

Comment: FYI: This is currently broken for 20.04 as there is no release in the PPA for "focal".

Comment: Correct, if you dig a bit deeper the ansible team has stated that they don't plan on updating the PPA for 20+ at the moment since it is packaged with native apt repos.